# Extracting information from a line with specific pattern using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this, i.e.

```
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF
```

Using the command line below, I extract information as a separate column for conf.

```
sed -Ei 's/(.*conf=)([^;]*)(;.*)/\1\2\3\t\2/g' my_file
```

However, if at the end of conf there is this symbol ; it works. Otherwise no. How to modify the script in order to extract the pattern in both cases,like this,and also in case it is empty to put tab?

```
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1  XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF  XF
```

I used this link as a reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414082/extract-part-of-lines-with-specific-pattern-and-store-in-a-new-field-using-awk-o?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: When you say `in case it is empty to put tab` - do you mean have a tab instead of `XF` in your above output or do you mean that the XFs above should be preceded by a tab and in the empty case it'd just be tab then null, or do you mean something else? Include that case in you sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually remove `;`:

```
sed -iE 's/(.*conf=)([^;]*)(.*)/\1\2\3\t\2/g'  my_file
```

The `[^;]*` is a negated bracket expression, it will only match 0 or more (due to `*`) chars other than `;`, and thus the `;` is not necessary to be present in the pattern itself, the preceding pattern is already "restricted".

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/8OfDTC):

```
s="A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF"
sed -E 's/(.*conf=)([^;]*)(.*)/\1\2\3\t\2/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following in `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/conf=[^;]*/){print $0,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5);next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program here.
match($0,/conf=[^;]*/){                      ##Using match function of awk to match regex from string conf= till semi colon comes.
   print $0,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)    ##Printing current line and then sub-string whose starting point of RSTART+5 and ending point is RLENGTH-5
   next                                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                            ##Closing BLOCK for match function here.
1                                            ##Mentioning 1 will print lines, those ones which are not having conf string match so it will simply print them.
'  Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have name=value input data I find it easiest, most robust, most flexible, etc. to create an array representing that relationship (`f[name]=value` below) so you can then just access the values by their names. Depending on what `in case it is empty to put tab` means:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:];=]+' -v OFS='\t' '
    {delete f; for (i=5; i<NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print $0, f["conf"]}
' file
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1     XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF     XF
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:];=]+' '
    {delete f; f["conf"]="\t"; for (i=5; i<NF; i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print $0, f["conf"]}
' file
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl one-liner

```
$ perl -lne ' /conf=(\w+)/ and $_.=" $1"; print ' conf.txt
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
$
```

or even shorter

```
$ perl -lne ' /conf=(\w+)/ and print "$_ $1" ' conf.txt
A   10  20  bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A   20  30  bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
```

Answer (score 1):

We should not require the `;` in `\3` -- as it is already handled in the exclusion character list in `\2`:

```
sed -Ei 's/(.*conf=)([^;]*)(.*)/\1\2\3\t\2/' my_file
```

If we need to contend with some other character than `;` as a delimiter, we include it in the character list in `\2`.  Such a character could be a `\t` or a space?

```
sed -Ei 's/(.*conf=)([^;\t ]*)(.*)/\1\2\3\t\2/' my_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A more or less straight copy [of my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509829/116858) to the question linked to in this question:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }

function get_attrib_by_name(key,  n,attrib,kv) {
    # Split the attribute field on semi-colons.
    n = split($5, attrib, ";")

    # Loop over the attributes and split each on "=".
    # When we've found the one we're looking for (by key name in "key"),
    # return the corresponding value.
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        split(attrib[i], kv, "=")
        if (kv[1] == key) {
            return kv[2]
        }
    }
}

# Using the above function.
{
    name = get_attrib_by_name("conf")
    print $0, name
}
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.gff
A       10      20      bob.1   ID=bob.1;Parent=bob;conf=XF;Note=bob_v1 XF
A       20      30      bob.2   ID=bob.2;Parent=bob;Note=bob_v1;conf=XF XF
```